# how to fix limit render loop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

i am currently building a chat app using react and Firebase real time database.

i have a problem with maximum limit rendering because of usecallback hook and users state (the hooks are addOnConnectLister addOnDisConnectListner).

this is the code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { Icon, Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";
import firebase from "../../firebase";

const DirectMessages = (props) => {
  const [usersRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref("users"));
  const [connectedRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref(".info/connected"));
  const [presenceRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref("presence"));
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  //add presence listner
  //create a presence record for current user
  const addPressenceListner = useCallback(
    (currentUserID) => {
      connectedRef.on("value", (snap) => {
        console.log("connecting snap value", snap.val());
        if (snap.val()) {
          const ref = presenceRef.child(currentUserID);
          ref.set(true);
       ref.onDisconnect().remove((err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
          });
        }
      });
    },
    [connectedRef, presenceRef]
  );


  //init connected users
  const initUsers = useCallback(
    (currentUserID) => {
      const loadedUsers = [];
      usersRef.on("child_added", (snap) => {
        if (currentUserID !== snap.key) {
          let user = snap.val();
          user["uid"] = snap.key;
          user["status"] = "offline";
          loadedUsers.push(user);
          setUsers([...loadedUsers]);
        }
      });
    },
    [usersRef]
  );

  //update user status when go online
  const addOnConnectListner = useCallback(() => {
    presenceRef.on("child_added", (snap) => {
      const updatedUsers = users.map((user) => {
        if (user.uid === snap.key) {
          console.log("user connected", user);
          user["status"] = "online";
        }
        return user;
      });
      setUsers(...[updatedUsers]);
    });
  }, [presenceRef, users]);

  //update user status when go offline
  const addOnDisconnectListner = useCallback(() => {
    presenceRef.on("child_removed", (snap) => {
      const updatedUsers = users.map((user) => {
        if (user.uid === snap.key) {
          console.log("user disconnected", user);
          user["status"] = "offline";
        }
        return user;
      });
      setUsers(updatedUsers);
    });
  }, [users, presenceRef]);

  const addListners = useCallback(
    (currentUserID) => {
      addPressenceListner(currentUserID);
      initUsers(currentUserID);
      addOnConnectListner();
      addOnDisconnectListner();
    },
    [
      addOnConnectListner,
      addOnDisconnectListner,
      addPressenceListner,
      initUsers,
    ]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.currentUser) {
      addListners(props.currentUser.uid);
    }
    return () => {
      presenceRef.off();
      usersRef.off();
      connectedRef.off();
    };
  }, [props.currentUser, addListners, connectedRef, presenceRef, usersRef]);

  const isUserOnline = (user) => user.status === "online";

  return (
    <Menu.Menu className="menu" style={{ paddingTop: "2em" }}>
      <Menu.Item>
        <span>
          <Icon name="mail" /> Direct Messages
        </span>{" "}
        ({users.length})
      </Menu.Item>

      {users.map((user) => (
        <Menu.Item key={user.uid}>
          <Icon name="circle" color={isUserOnline(user) ? "green" : "red"} />@
          {user.username}
        </Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu.Menu>
  );
};

export default DirectMessages;
```

after searching i found a solution using useRef to get a reference of users state to avoid the problem but is not working correctly the callback is runnging only once

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { Icon, Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";
import firebase from "../../firebase";

const DirectMessages = (props) => {
  const [usersRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref("users"));
  const [connectedRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref(".info/connected"));
  const [presenceRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref("presence"));
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  //users state ref
  const getUsersRef = useRef(users);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersRef.current = users;
  }, [users]);

  //add presence listner
  //create a presence record for current user
  const addPressenceListner = useCallback(
    (currentUserID) => {
      connectedRef.on("value", (snap) => {
        console.log("connecting snap value", snap.val());
        if (snap.val()) {
          const ref = presenceRef.child(currentUserID);
          ref.set(true);
          ref.onDisconnect().remove((err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
          });
        }
      });
    },
    [connectedRef, presenceRef]
  );


  //init connected users
  const initUsers = useCallback(
    (currentUserID) => {
      const loadedUsers = [];
      usersRef.on("child_added", (snap) => {
        if (currentUserID !== snap.key) {
          let user = snap.val();
          user["uid"] = snap.key;
          user["status"] = "offline";
          loadedUsers.push(user);
          setUsers([...loadedUsers]);
        }
      });
    },
    [usersRef]
  );

  //update user status when go online
  const addOnConnectListner = useCallback(() => {
    presenceRef.on("child_added", (snap) => {
      const updatedUsers = getUsersRef.current.map((user) => {
        if (user.uid === snap.key) {
          console.log("user connected", user);
          user["status"] = "online";
        }
        return user;
      });
      setUsers(...[updatedUsers]);
    });
  }, [presenceRef, getUsersRef]);

  //update user status when go offline
  const addOnDisconnectListner = useCallback(() => {
    presenceRef.on("child_removed", (snap) => {
      const updatedUsers = getUsersRef.current.map((user) => {
        if (user.uid === snap.key) {
          console.log("user disconnected", user);
          user["status"] = "offline";
        }
        return user;
      });
      setUsers(updatedUsers);
    });
  }, [getUsersRef, presenceRef]);

  const addListners = useCallback(
    (currentUserID) => {
      addPressenceListner(currentUserID);
      initUsers(currentUserID);
      addOnConnectListner();
      addOnDisconnectListner();
    },
    [
      addOnConnectListner,
      addOnDisconnectListner,
      addPressenceListner,
      initUsers,
    ]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.currentUser) {
      addListners(props.currentUser.uid);
    }
    return () => {
      presenceRef.off();
      usersRef.off();
      connectedRef.off();
    };
  }, [props.currentUser, addListners, connectedRef, presenceRef, usersRef]);

  const isUserOnline = (user) => user.status === "online";

  return (
    <Menu.Menu className="menu" style={{ paddingTop: "2em" }}>
      <Menu.Item>
        <span>
          <Icon name="mail" /> Direct Messages
        </span>{" "}
        ({users.length})
      </Menu.Item>

      {users.map((user) => (
        <Menu.Item key={user.uid}>
          <Icon name="circle" color={isUserOnline(user) ? "green" : "red"} />@
          {user.username}
        </Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu.Menu>
  );
};

export default DirectMessages;
```

Comment: why do you use `return` in the useEffect? `return` is used for cleanup in `useEffect` hook. Try removing it.

Comment: forgot to edit the question still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing this:

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  //users state ref
  const getUsersRef = useRef(users);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersRef.current = users;
  }, [users]);
```

to this:

```
  //users state ref
  const getUsersRef = useRef(users);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersRef.current = users;
  }, [users]);
```

after updating hooks dependencies :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useRef } from "react";
import { Icon, Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";
import firebase from "../../firebase";

const usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users");
const connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
const presenceRef = firebase.database().ref("presence");

const DirectMessages = (props) => {
  const [users, _setUsers] = useState([]);

  //get users ref
  const getUsersRef = useRef(users);

  const setUsers = (array) => {
    getUsersRef.current = array;
    _setUsers(array);
  };

  //add presence listner
  //create a presence record for current user
  const addPressenceListner = useCallback((currentUserID) => {
    connectedRef.on("value",(snap) => {
      console.log("connecting snap value", snap.val());
      if (snap.val()) {
        const ref = presenceRef.child(currentUserID);
        ref.set(true);
        ref.onDisconnect().remove((err) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  //init connected users
  const initUsers = useCallback((currentUserID) => {
    const loadedUsers = [];
    usersRef.on("child_added", (snap) => {
      if (currentUserID !== snap.key) {
        let user = snap.val();
        user["uid"] = snap.key;
        user["status"] = "offline";
        loadedUsers.push(user);
        setUsers([...loadedUsers]);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  //update user status when go online
  const addOnConnectListner = useCallback(() => {
    presenceRef.on("child_added", (snap) => {
      const updatedUsers = getUsersRef.current.map((user) => {
        if (user.uid === snap.key) {
          user["status"] = "online";
        }
        console.log("user", user);
        return user;
      });
      setUsers(...[updatedUsers]);
    });
  }, []);

  //update user status when go offline
  const addOnDisconnectListner = useCallback(() => {
    presenceRef.on("child_removed", (snap) => {
      const updatedUsers = getUsersRef.current.map((user) => {
        if (user.uid === snap.key) {
          console.log("user disconnected", user);
          user["status"] = "offline";
        }
        return user;
      });
      setUsers(updatedUsers);
    });
  }, [getUsersRef]);

  const addListners = useCallback(
    (currentUserID) => {
      addPressenceListner(currentUserID);
      initUsers(currentUserID);
      addOnConnectListner();
      addOnDisconnectListner();
    },
    [
      addOnConnectListner,
      addOnDisconnectListner,
      addPressenceListner,
      initUsers,
    ]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.currentUser) {
      addListners(props.currentUser.uid);
    }
    return () => {
      presenceRef.off();
      usersRef.off();
      connectedRef.off();
    };
  }, [props.currentUser, addListners]);

  const isUserOnline = (user) => user.status === "online";

  return (
    <Menu.Menu className="menu" style={{ paddingTop: "2em" }}>
      <Menu.Item>
        <span>
          <Icon name="mail" /> Direct Messages
        </span>{" "}
        ({users.length})
      </Menu.Item>

      {users.map((user) => (
        <Menu.Item key={user.uid}>
          <Icon name="circle" color={isUserOnline(user) ? "green" : "red"} />@
          {user.username}
        </Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu.Menu>
  );
};

export default DirectMessages;
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you do not need them as state

```
  const [usersRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref("users"));
  const [connectedRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref(".info/connected"));
  const [presenceRef] = useState(firebase.database().ref("presence"));
```

set them outside the component.

```
const usersRef = firebase.database().ref("users")
const connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected")
const presenceRef = firebase.database().ref("presence")

const DirectMessages = (props) => {
......
```

Secondly, the correct way to remove the listeners are.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (props.currentUser) {
      addListners(props.currentUser.uid);
    return () => {
      presenceRef.off('child_added');
      presenceRef.off('child_removed');
      usersRef.off('child_added');
      connectedRef.off('value');
    };
    }

  }, [props.currentUser, addListners, connectedRef, presenceRef, usersRef]);
```

I will change the following

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  //users state ref
  const getUsersRef = useRef(users);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersRef.current = users;
  }, [users]);
```

to

```
  const [users, _setUsers] = useState([]);
  const getUsersRef = useRef(users);

  const setUsers = (array) => {
        getUsersRef.current = array;
        _setUsers(array)
  }
```

**lastly**, the usecallbacks are unnecessary, you should create them as regular functions.

```
  const addOnDisconnectListner = () => {
    presenceRef.on("child_removed", (snap) => {
      const updatedUsers = getUsersRef.current.map((user) => {
        if (user.uid === snap.key) {
          console.log("user disconnected", user);
          user["status"] = "offline";
        }
        return user;
      });
      setUsers(updatedUsers);
    }
```

Comment: i agree with the first point , and i know about removing the listeners but i cant't change useCallback to regular function because the making dependency of useEffect and other callbacks igot the following linting err: The 'addListners' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 95) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'addListners' in its own useCallback() Hook."

Comment: that's an error message? actually u don't event need those dependencies in your use effect. because u want your use effect to run only once

Comment: [props.currentUser, addListners, connectedRef, presenceRef, usersRef] <- u can remove all of them except props.currentUser

Comment: you can read the following docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html