# React Native updating only after I save file

Tags: react-native, stock

I have an application that queries the stock exchange in real time, but when I open the application the first time it does not update any displayed value, as if it were hardcoded, but when I save the file (ctrl + S) it starts to update normally , Can anyone help me with this?

description code below:

> this function is listening the data on firebase;
> ticketRT is my state that is not updating at first time

```
 Object.keys(subscriptionStocks).forEach((stock) => {
        if(!subscriptionStocks[stock].listener) {
          firebase.database().ref(`${endPointStocks}/${stock}`).on('value', async data => {
            let stock = data.val();
            if (stock) {
              stockArray[stock.ticket] = stock;
              setTicketRT(stockArray);
              await updateListStocks(stock);
            } else {
              console.log(`[listenerStock]: Não foi possível cadastrar o ativo "${stock}"`);
            }
          });
          subscriptionStocks[stock].listener = true;
```

> this function updates the stock list

```
 let tmpStock = {};
      console.log('LENGTH 11111', stockArray.length);
      if (stockArray.length === 0) {
        console.log('LENGTH 22222 ≥≥≥ 2', stockArray.length);
        tmpStock[stock.ticket] = stock;
        stockArray.push(tmpStock);
        setTicketRT(stockArray);
        updateWalletBalance();
      } else {
        const foundStockInArray = stockArray.some(
          el => {
            let inStock = el[Object.keys(el)[0]];
            return inStock.ticket == stock.ticket;
          }
        );

        if (foundStockInArray) {
          updateStock(stock);
        } else {
          tmpStock[stock.ticket] = stock; 
          stockArray.push(tmpStock);
          setTicketRT(stockArray);
          updateWalletBalance();
        }
      }
```

> this is my FlatList that is not updating

```
<FlatList
                  style={styles.actionList}
                  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                  data={ticketRT}
                  extraData={(item, index) => {
                    if(ticketRT !== undefined) {
                      let stocks = ticketRT[index];
                      let stock = stocks[Object.keys(stocks)[0]];
                      return stock.ticket;
                    }
                  }}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index ) => {
                    if(ticketRT !== undefined) {
                      let stocks = ticketRT[index];
                      let stock = stocks[Object.keys(stocks)[0]];
                      return stock.ticket;
                    }
                  }}
                  renderItem={({ index }) => {
                    let stocks = ticketRT[index];
                    let stock = stocks[Object.keys(stocks)[0]];
                    return <Ativos data={stock} />
                  }}
                  contentInset={{ bottom: 10, top: -5 }}
                />
```

ALL CODE IS FOUNDED HERE: https://gist.github.com/paulorod07/4e74976345a6a68b0e32755cf5ae1c46

Comment: provide codes for entire component please thank u

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I create a GitHub gist with all code: https://gist.github.com/paulorod07/4e74976345a6a68b0e32755cf5ae1c46 help me please

Comment: I see u use stockArray multiple times but I don't see declaration for stockArray

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial is at line 161 in my gist

Comment: well then that could be the problem, because stockArray is being reinitiated as an empty array on every render. You can either put stockArray outside the component function, OR better still, use useRef. I provide some similar answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65060420/2822041